# Filter Criteria by attribute with @Convert

Tags: spring, postgresql, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a simple class with a list of Strings and this list is converted to be one column in db with @Convert and now i'm trying to create a criteria based on type attrbute.

```
@Entity(name = "my_table")
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
  private List<String> type;
}
```

and criteria : 
    `c2.add(Restrictions.ilike("type", matchValue, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));`

but I got this exception :

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter
```

*all entries have a value and I use a psql db

Comment: Do you find any workaround?

Comment: Nope :( .......

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible right now with Hibernate.

Please see the bug ticket: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9991

Answer (score 0):

workaround:

```
@Column
@Convert(converter = LanguageVersionsConverter.class)
private LanguageVersions languages;

@Column(name = "languages", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String languagesRaw;
```

```
@QueryExpression(fields = {"language"})
public <T> Predicate filterByLanguages(
  QueryConditionExpression param, CriteriaBuilder cb, From<Course, T> from) {
var field = "languagesRaw";
var value = param.getValue();
switch (param.getOperator()) {
  case EQUAL:
    return cb.equal(from.get(field), value);
  default:
    return cb.like(from.get(field), "%" + value + "%");
}
}
```

define another field to use Criteria API.